# is it reasonable to make models inherit from NotificationObject in Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel namespace?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm refactoring my wpf application with Prism. My previous models implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface, now, I found there's a NotificationObject class which is already implement this interface in Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel namespace, I use it directly with my ViewModels, but is it reasonable to use it with my models? It is strange to use a namespace which named 'ViewModel' in Models. Or is there any other trick in Prism which I didn't find? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some say yes, others say no. I say yes because `INotifyPropertyChanged` is nothing to do with the View. e.g. EntityFramework Entity's implement it.

Why do same say No? Probably because `INotifyPropertyChanged` lives in the System.ComponentModel Namespace and if your ViewModels project is separate from your View one, MVVM can be enforced by not referencing the assembly.

I am all for minimalism and code re-use so like to bind to directly my Model rather than duplicate the data on the ViewModel. And you should always implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on anything you bind to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged with my models. I'm confused why this property is implemented in Pism.ViewModel Namespace, is there any other way to notify property chagned with the models in Prism? Or working with some other modules with Prism, I needn't to inherit NotificationObject? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can always go ahead an do your own implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged, i.e. keep you old models as they were. Everything should just work - it raises the same event WPF listens for. I am not familiar with Prism - if they require a NotificationObject then I guess you would need to use that :-/